# MongoDB on Redhat failed to start

Tags: mongodb

```
[mdbuser@mongoserv ~]$ systemctl status mongod
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor pres>
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2022-12-18 08:00:32 IST; 32min >
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 1400 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 1393 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb (code=exited,>
  Process: 1372 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mdbuser:mdbgroup /var/run/mongodb (>
  Process: 1341 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, s>

Dec 18 08:00:30 mongoserv systemd[1]: Starting MongoDB Database Server...
Dec 18 08:00:32 mongoserv systemd[1]: mongod.service: Control process exited, c>
Dec 18 08:00:32 mongoserv systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit->
Dec 18 08:00:32 mongoserv systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
 ESCOC
```

I have configured the paths of log, data and expected to start the server

Comment: Would you repost with `systemctl --no-pager --full status mongod`?

Comment: MongoDB exit code 2 means `The specified options are in error or are incompatible with other options`, the options and config aren't shown, so I can't comment on what might be wrong with them.

Comment: Check the mongod logfile, typically at `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`